# Another question concerning p and t

Tags: set-theory

I refer to an article concerning p and t :
edited Sep 14 '17 at 2:48 / Bjørn Kjos-Hanssen
answered Sep 13 '17 at 21:50 / Mark Fischler

I already asked a question December 14th 2018 and I received among others this answer from Alex Kruckman Dec 14 at 21:50 (thank you Alex) :
... you're correct that {2 to the power of m! : m∈ℕ} is a pseudo-intersection of the family ({m to the power of k : m∈ℕ})k∈ℕ.

I have please another question, now concerning t : could someone give me an example of a family respecting the finite-intersection criteria and fully ordered by the relation 'almost included', and yet however having no pseudo-intersection ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: By Zorn's lemma, just take a maximal such linearly ordered family. If it had a pseudo-intersection, it wouldn't be maximal. Have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

By Zorn's lemma, there is a maximal such linearly ordered family. If it had a pseudo-intersection, it wouldn't be maximal.

I suppose there is a question remaining concerning whether one can prove that there is such a family without using the axiom of choice. I'm not quite sure about that.

Comment: Rather, not quite?